# How to quickly debug Flutter benchmark test (performance profiling) code?

Tags: flutter, dart, testing

I am writing some performance profiling (benchmark) test code as suggested here: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/profiling. However, the documentation suggests I should run it like:

```
flutter drive --driver=test_driver/perf_driver.dart --target=integration_test/scrolling_test.dart --profile
```

As we know, that will need even minutes to run once even if only changed one line of code, because it goes through the whole Android/iOS compilation. That takes a lot of time when debugging the correctness of my test code.

On the other hand, we know Flutter has powerful hot reload/restart which only takes seconds to reload code changes. Can we utilize that to easily debug benchmark test code?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share my approach here:

You can run

```
flutter run integration_test/scrolling_test.dart --no-dds
```

and that is all. You can *hot restart* now for free! (The `--no-dds` in my case is needed because otherwise it errors; but in your case it may not be needed.)

But bear in mind some drawbacks:

- To allow hot restart, it should be run in debug mode, but profiling/benchmarking should only be run in profile mode or the numbers are completely useless. Thus, *only* debug the *correctness* of your code and never trust the numbers in this mode.
- It will not collect data and write to host machine after tests finished in this approach, because no driver (e.g. `test_driver/perf_driver.dart`) exists. But since we should not use the numbers in this mode, it is no problem.